# How to convert void* type in C to string type in python?

Tags: python, c, cython

I tried to convert `void*` type in C to `string` in python when using Cython to wrapper C language, but I don't know how to convert the `void*` type to `string`, when converting the C `int` to python `Py_ssize_t`, like(a part of a class):

```
cpdef int peek_tail(self):
    cdef int value = <Py_ssize_t>cqueue.queue_peek_tail(self._c_queue)
```

When I want to convert it to `string`, how can I define it?

```
cpdef ? peek_tail(self):
    cdef ? value = <?>cqueue.queue_peek_tail(self._c_queue)
```

The `?` is what I want. Any documents exist?

Comment: What do you mean by" convert"? Does the `void *`-pointer point to  a python-string and you want to **cast** it to a string-object? Or can it be any `PyObject *` and you want to convert it to its string-representation?

Comment: And having `cqueue` (whatever that is) in the question doesn't add much to clarity - rather the opposite..

Comment: @ead I assume a `cqueue` is taken from [this tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html). It doesn't change the fact that some unknown type has been hidden behind a `void*` and somehow this should be converted to a string without knowing how it was put there...

Comment: @littlely There's another thing to worry about here - if you're planning to use C strings (`char*`) you may need to think about managing the memory. How you do that depends on where the C strings come from (string literals, generated in C e.g. `sprintf`, or converted from Python strings). Unfortunately there isn't an obvious right way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `char*` on `cdef` but since your using `cpdef` you can just can also do `str` for bytes (py2) or unicode (py3). I believe the `queue_peek_tail` return is always `Py_ssize_t`.

See [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html) for more specfic info. Especially the line

> Generally speaking: unless you know what you are doing, avoid using C strings where possible and use Python string objects instead.

Comment: Can it convert to PyObject*, so I can add python object?